# Is there a way to use same name for module and submodule in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

modules with the same name as submodules seem to import only from submodules.

For example, I have the following directory tree

```
module/
  a.py
  b.py
  __init__.py
  test/
    a.py
    b.py
    __init__.py
```

where the first `__init__.py` is like

```
module/__init__.py

from .a import *
from .b import *
from .test import *
```

and the second one is

```
module/test/__init__.py

from .a import *
from .b import *
```

When I import the module, it seems like it only imports modules from `module/test/`.

```
import module

module.a
>> <module 'module.test.a' from './module/test/a.py'>

module.test.a
>> <module 'module.test.a' from './module/test/a.py'>
```

But what I expect is

```
import module

module.a
>> <module 'module.a' from './module/a.py'>

module.test.a
>> <module 'module.test.a' from './module/test/a.py'>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: OK, I think I have solved the problem. I just changed the import order in the first __init__.py. If anyone else have a better idea pleas leave a comment or answer. Thx

Comment: I am wondering why you would import from `test` in `module/__init__.py` ... normally tests would import from the regular code you want to test, but not vice versa

Comment: So my intention was that the `test` directory contains the same functions as regular files which are located under module/ but with new updated features not yet implemented in regular files. I thought it would be nice if I could try new features just by importing from `module.test`.